# File upload click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my problem.I have made function for file upload.But when I click on the button upload show me modal for choosing file.This is ok but after get file and click open this modal show me again and after second choise function end.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById('file_alt').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    debugger;
    let file = document.getElementById('file');
    var fileName = $('#fileName');

    file.click();
    $(file).on('change', function(e) {

      let fileText = e.target.files[0].name;
      fileName.val(fileText);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-12 m-2 mt-4" id="fileForm">
  <input type="file" name="file" value="" id="file" style="display:none" />
  <button name="fileName" id="file_alt" class="btn btn-danger" type="button" value="">Прикачи</button>
  <input type="text" id="fileName" name="FileName" value="" readonly style="border:none" />

  <label for="file"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem. Could you try to clarify it a bit please? Maybe in a *1) click the button 2) choose a file 3) click again...*  list?

Comment: Why you mix vanilla JS and jQuery? It's very confusing...

Comment: use fileinput's change event rather than click event

Comment: @SumitBadaya the code already does that. Look more carefully at which element has a click event and which has a change event...

Comment: I meant the change event should be fine rather than need of click event. Understand more properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I didn't fully understand your description of the problem, but I can't see such an issue occurring in your demo code.

However I would suggest a couple of things to improve the code more generally:

1) Be consistent in your syntax - either use vanilla JS syntax, or use jQuery syntax. Mixing them together makes the code harder to read. I've used jQuery throughout in my example.

2) Move the "change" event outside the "click" event handler. When it's inside the click handler, this means that every time you click the button, it adds another "change" event handler to the file input. Adding a new handler does not remove the older ones. This means the next time you choose a file after that, it will run *all* the change handler functions you previously added. If you watch carefully in your code you'll see it very quickly show each of the names of all the previously selected files in turn, before replacing them with the later ones. This is the effect of all those functions running one after another. You don't need the function to run more than once, so if you declare it outside the "click" handler, it will create the event handler once when the page loads.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var file = $('#file');
  $('#file_alt').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    file.click();
  });

  $(file).on('change', function(e) {
    let fileText = e.target.files[0].name;
    $('#fileName').val(fileText);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-12 m-2 mt-4" id="fileForm">
  <input type="file" name="file" value="" id="file" style="display:none" />
  <button name="fileName" id="file_alt" class="btn btn-danger" type="button" value="">Прикачи</button>
  <input type="text" id="fileName" name="FileName" value="" readonly style="border:none" />

  <label for="file"></label>
</div>
```